# Am charts bullets overlapping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amcharts

As shown in the image there are 2 squares(150 y axis) which are overlapping, I want to show them separately, how can I do it?
[image]

here is the code square bullets:

```
var diaGraph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    diaGraph.valueAxis = bpValueAxis;
    diaGraph.valueField = "diastolic";
    diaGraph.balloonText = "DIA:[[diastolic]] "+uom+"<br><p style='font-size:9px;max-width:300px; word-wrap: break-word;'>[[alert_text]]</p>";
    diaGraph.colorField = "bullet_color";
    diaGraph.lineColor = "#808080";
    diaGraph.bullet = "square";
    chartBP.addGraph(diaGraph);
```

Comment: Plz upload your code

Comment: @MakwanaPrahlad please look at the code